# Detect if and when any jQuery AJAX calls are made

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a toolbar that exists on all my webpages that makes requests to a server side XML file regularly.

Some of the web pages also make requests to the same XML file, but more frequently. Ideally I would like to, where possible, combine this easily into a single request. Where the toolbar uses the same request that the page made (as the page refresh rate is greater than that of the toolbar)

Is there any way to tell if any jQuery AJAX calls have been made to a certain resources and, if so, be notified on success?

***Update:***

Based on Darin Dimitrov's answer I have tried the following:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
   success: function(){ console.log("woop"); }
 });
```

This never fires, I presume because the success handler is being overwritten when I make my other AJAX calls.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the [`$.ajaxSetup()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/) to subscribe for the common events.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply, unfortunately this seems to only work for default options, i.e. if I set up the following (see update on original Q)

Comment: @Chris, try subscribing for the `complete` callback.

Comment: How do I find out which URL was called?

Answer (score 1):

Subscribe to all ajax events at the document level;

```
$(document).bind("ajaxSend", function(){
   alert('ajax fired');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In your AJAX add response callback, something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "mypage.php",
    data: "name=John&location=Boston",
success: function(data){
     alert(data);
    }
});
```

and on your php page where you process AJAX request add some echo statement:

```
echo "POSTed OK!";
```

If you post is a success you'll get an alert confirmation.
You can also get a confirmation if it failes but modifying the code slightly:

```
success: function(result) {
    if (result==1) {
        alert('Success');
    } else {
        alert('Failed');
    }
}
```

Good luck!